# Css Aside tag placement

Tags: css, html

Is their a way that i can center the aside content on my site
actually i have widget area which is custom menu

was not able to center the navigation on the [site](http://d3sign.biz/test/)

which is right now right aligned

i have removed the `float:right`of the aside  &

tried few things like

```
.genesis-nav-menu {   float: right;   width: 1140px; }
```

although it helped me slightly i have issue in responsiveness of the theme 
so what is the way to make it responsive as well as content width.
the theme is using 
html5 aside tag

need : "center the menu , content width navaigation (1140px) ,reponsiveness intact"

Comment: try `.site-header .genesis-nav-menu {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: auto;
}`

Comment: the above setting are again taking back nav to left align